# Is this valid table create syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Given a design of:

```
Player
===========
PlayerID
TeamID
FirstName
LastName
DateOfBirth

Team
===========
TeamID
TeamName
Grade

Match
===========
MatchID
HomeTeamID
AwayTeamID
Date
Result
```

I am using this:

```
 CREATE TABLE Match(
   MatchID VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
   Dateofmatch date,
   Result VARCHAR2(1) ,
   HomeTeam VARCHAR2(5),
   AwayTeam VARCHAR2(5),
   CONSTRAINT MatchPK PRIMARY KEY(MatchID),
   CONSTRAINT HomeFK FOREIGN KEY(HomeTeamIDFK) REFERENCES TEAM(TeamID),
   CONSTRAINT AwayFK FOREIGN KEY(AwayTeamIDFK) REFERENCES TEAM(TeamID),
   CONSTRAINT Result
   Check (Result in (‘W’,’L’,’D’)
   );
```

to create the Match table assuming that Match ID,Player ID and teamID colums are of data type `VARCHAR2(5)`. The result of the match refers to homeTeam and can only be W,L or D.

Is this correct?

---

I have come out with this kindly correct me

```
CREATE TABLE Match (
    MatchID VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
    Dateofmatch date,
    Result VARCHAR2(1) ,
    HomeTeam VARCHAR2(5),
    AwayTeam VARCHAR2(5),
    CONSTRAINT MatchPK PRIMARY KEY(MatchID),
    CONSTRAINT HomeFK FOREIGN KEY(HomeTeamIDFK) REFERENCES TEAM(TeamID),
    CONSTRAINT AwayFK FOREIGN KEY(AwayTeamIDFK) REFERENCES TEAM(TeamID),
    CONSTRAINT Result Check (Result in (‘W’,’L’,’D’)
);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: This looks a lot like you have not spend any time googling for any hint on the create syntax. I suggest you find documentation for creating tables in SQL and try building the statement on your own. If you should get stuck, come back here and ask specific questions. To try your statement, you can use an open sql interface, for instance http://www-db.in.tum.de/~muehe/sql/

Comment: `VARCHAR2` is an **Oracle** datatype, not a MySQL datatype.

Comment: You have an unbalanced open parenthesis, so the syntax is wrong.  You also have a comma at the end with nothing after it, so the syntax is wrong again.

Comment: What happened when you tried the syntax in the question?  Would it not have been quicker to find out than to ask the question?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: "ENABLE" is also an Oracle thing, not a MySQL thing.

Comment: @Henrik: Any thing approaching standard SQL is a bad choice for testing MySQL. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) will let you test on a MySQL server.

Comment: Hi, If you have another question please ask one. This is a question and answer site not a forum so consistently adding answers isn't going to get you anywhere. Please ensure that you've searched for the answer to your question _before_ asking though and explain in your question _exactly_ what you've tried and why it isn't working.

Comment: How do i reference the score to the home team and away team???

Answer (score 1):

I would aim for something more like:

```
CREATE TABLE match
   ( match_id INTEGER, 
     date_of_match  DATE, 
     result_type  char(1), 
     home_team_id INTEGER, 
     away_team_id INTEGER,
     CONSTRAINT match_pk PRIMARY KEY(match_id),
     CONSTRAINT home_fk FOREIGN KEY(home_team_id_fk) REFERENCES TEAM(team_id),
     CONSTRAINT away_fk FOREIGN KEY(away_team_id_fk) REFERENCES TEAM(team_id)
     CONSTRAINT result_type CHECK (result_type in (‘W’,’L’,’D’)
  )
```

I know the datatypes for the fk's are supposed to be varchar2(5) but I suggest they either be changed or you find those tables true primary key which would be an integer or have one added.  It's the right thing to do (though opinions will vary).

Comment: Next qns is i must then include a column that records both socres of the teams. a team would nv score more than 999 in a match.
My answer 
ALTER TABLE Match
ADD Score VARCHAR(2)
ADD CONSTRAINT Score CHECK (Score<99)